# The last few search results are hidden behind keyboard

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a search bar positioned above a tableview. The search functionality works great.

The problem is when there are more than 4 search results, the other results are hidden behind the popped up keyboard. Is there an easy way to resize the tableview that contains the results only while searching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I was looking to do was resize the tableview while the keyboard was active. Here's how to do it:

```
CGFloat height = (self.tableView.frame.size.height/2);
CGFloat width = self.tableView.frame.size.width;

CGRect halfFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
tableView.frame = halfFrame;
```

When the keyboard is removed, use this code to resize the tableview back to normal:

```
CGFloat height = (self.tableView.frame.size.height*2);
CGFloat width = self.tableView.frame.size.width;

CGRect fullFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
tableView.frame = fullFrame;
```